# In Einstein's thought experiment does each one event consist of one part taking place on the embankment and a distinct part taking place on the train?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, foundations

In Einstein's original thought experiment involving *"a (very long) train running along a [straight] railway embankment"*, of essential importance appears [the prescription that](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/286?highlightText=event)

> *"[E]very event which takes place along the [railway track] line also takes place at a particular point of the train."*

The constituents of the train are surely distinct from the constituents of the railway embankment and track (especially since they are supposed to have moved wrt. each other; each constituent of the train and each constituent of the track segment under consideration have separately met each other in passing).

Is it consequently correct to say that each separate event involving train and embankment/track has **one particular constituent of the train** and **one particular constituent of the track** as participants in this event, such that this particular pair uniquely identifies the event ?,

and that each such event has two distinct parts, namely

- **one distinctive part attributable to the participating train constituent** (which is characterized by the train constituent indicating being met, in passing, by the track constituent; perhaps with additional characterizations), and
- **another distinctive part attributable to the participating embankment/track constituent** (being vice versa foremost characterized by the track constituent indicating being met, in passing, by the train cconstituent)

?

Note that the event-parts in question are not presumed to be separate from each other, or resolvable, in a geometric (spatial) sense. My question is not whether and how certain sets of (finely-resolved) distinct events may be considered and addressed as one (coarsely-resolved) event; nor whether any one actual particle (or even several) may be considered fully contained in any spacetime region of finite spatial extent.

**My question is rather conceptually:**

**Whether (at all) and (if so) How to reconcile**

- speaking of an event as "having distinguishable parts", as described above, while also
- speaking of an event as [*"a point in spacetime"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Definitions), or [*"a point of spacetime"*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22point+of+spacetime%22) with the understanding that: [*"A point has no part(s)."*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(geometry)#Points_in_Euclidean_geometry)

?

Comment: An event is just a spacetime point $(t,x,y,z)$. Period. Full stop. In another frame the same event will have different coordinates $(t’,x’,y’,z’)$. An event has no parts because it is just a point. Everything about distinctive parts is a misunderstanding. Nothing necessarily happens at an event. An event specifies where-and-when something *could* happen.

Comment: An event *can* be where and when multiple objects interact, such as the place and time that an electron and a positron annihilate and create two photons. But the four particles that happen to interact at this event are not “parts” of the event.

Comment: It is always easy to tell how much a student has absorbed just by noticing how they describe things: You are essentially saying that you can use two points, say the most front wheel and the most back wheel's point of contact with the track to define the time. But if you measure this "at the same time" from the point of view of the embankment, the people on the train will disagree that it is at the same time. That is the whole point of SR

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent: _"the whole point of SR"_ -- Stay tuned for my upcoming question "The definition of simultaneity applied in a thought experiment involving three handshake events" (in preparation).

Comment: @Ghoster: _"particles that happen to interact"_ -- Matches: ["_All our space-time verifications invariably amount to determination of space-time coincidences {... such as ...}  meetings of two or more material points._"](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/165?highlightText=coincidences)). _"are not “parts” of the event."_ –- Agreed: Any particle has significant temporal extent. Only a ("momentary") part of this extent is also part of an event. To suggest a name: "indication". _"An event has no parts [...]"_ -- Please consider expanding to an answer. I'm not obliged to accept.

Answer (score 3):

All Einstein is stating is that at any given point along the platform at any given time there will be some point immediately alongside it on the train. So an event that takes place at some point along the edge of the platform also takes place at the point on the side of the train that happens to be alongside at the time.

If you want to consider another analogy, take a moving walkway of the sort you find at airports, and imagine that there are people all along it and people all along the ground next to it. As each person on the moving walkway passes a stationary person alongside the walkway they shake hands. Each handshake is an event that takes place at a given point on the ground and at a given point on the walkway.

Comment: Marco Ocram: _"All Einstein is stating is that at any given point along the platform at any given time there will be some point immediately alongside it on the train."_ -- Einstein doesn't use the word _"time"_ at all in the descriptions [on the referenced page](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/286), nor even on the following page. Instead, he writes of _"events"_. ... [contd.]

Comment: Marco Ocram: _"[...] As each person on the moving walkway passes a stationary person alongside the walkway they shake hands."_ -- Excellent example. _"Each handshake is an event"_ -- Distinguishable participants ("hand of walkway person" vs. "hand of stationary person"), right? And (if so): With distinct parts (where each one part is associated only to one participant); e.g. "One hand indicating pain from being squeezed" vs. "The other hand indicating shock from the touching hand being unexpectedly cold.", together constituting one event. So: answer "Yes.", please.